# Python-based PDF parser integrated with Zapier

Tags: python, zapier

I am working for a company which is currently storing PDF files into a remote drive and subsequently manually inserting values found within these files into an Excel document. I would like to automate the process using Zapier, and make the process scalable (we receive a large amount of PDF files). Would anyone know any applications useful and possibly free for converting PDFs into Excel docs and which integrate with Zapier? Alternatively, would it be possible to create a Python script in Zapier to access the information and store it into an Excel file?

Answer (score 0):

This option came to mind. I'm using google drive as an example, you didn't say what you where using as storage, but Zapier should have an option for it.

Use cloud convert, doc parser (depends on what you want to pay, cloud convert at least gives you some free time per month, so that may be the closest you can get).

Create a zap with this step:

1. Trigger on new file in drive (Name: Convert new Google Drive files with CloudConvert)
2. Convert file with CloudConvert

Those are two options by Zapier that I can find. But you could also do it in python from your desktop by following something like [this idea](https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2018/05/03/exporting-data-from-pdfs-with-python/). Then set an event controller in windows event manager to trigger an upload/download.

Unfortunately it doesn't seem that you can import JS/Python libraries into zapier, however I may be wrong on that. If you could, or find a way to do so, then just use [PDFminer](https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2018/05/03/exporting-data-from-pdfs-with-python/) and "Code by Zapier". A technician might have to confirm this though, I've never gotten libraries to work in zaps.

Hope that helps!